# How to report your own post as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

What if I notice I accidentally have made a duplicate post. Should I delete my post or should I link to the original/earlier post? If so, how can I do this?

**Edit:**

After reading this [Is there any value to NOT deleting my own duplicate question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157389/is-there-any-value-to-not-deleting-my-own-duplicate-question) it is clear I should not delete my duplicate posts. Though, now how do I report duplicate posts?

Comment: @shadow that's not discussing *how* to close your own question as a duplicate.

Comment: You can vote to close your own question, so choose to close as duplicate. You can also leave a comment linking to the dupe, then high rep users who see it can cast more votes.

Comment: @Servy but "Should I delete my post or should I link to the original/earlier post?" is. In my opinion, question body is what matters, not title.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's asking both questions.  The linked duplicate answers one of the two questions, but not the other.

Comment: @Servy so it should be asked as two separate questions in the first place. I stand behind my decision on this one.

Comment: @ShadowWizard To close a post as a duplicate that *doesn't answer the question that's asked*?

Comment: @Servy like I said, the original question here is "Should I delete my post or should I link to the original/earlier post?". The accepted answer in the other question clearly says "No, you should not delete if it's duplicate". So that's a dupe. Feel free to reopen, I won't fight it but like I said, I believe I am right.

Comment: The original question was in the title. The additional question, was just added as a matter of completeness to the whole issue. I notice that I was wrong in doing so, but obviously the second question was what I wanted to ask as the title indicates. Should I just edit the content of the question?

Comment: @ShadowWizard So the title just doesn't exist at all, nor does his first sentance, or the second half of the second sentence, or the last sentence, or the entirety of the edit?  All of that is just invalid and the half of the second sentence that is relevant is all that matters?

Comment: @Servy I can't fix the world. The question is messy and I've made my decision, taking what I thought was most important. The "how to close" is rather simple, while "should I delete or not" is more open for discussion. Bottom line, guess we'll have to agree to disagree here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The fact that you can't fix the world doesn't mean you should close this question as a duplicate when it is not in fact a duplicate.  The question isn't messy at all.  Particularly after the edit there is *no question whatsoever* that it is not answered by the duplicate.  This is made explicit by the OP *telling you that his question is not answered by the duplicate*.  The fact that you think half of the question is more "interesting" and half of it is "boring" doesn't mean you can just ignore what bores you.

Comment: @Servy no. It's more like he got answer for one question and now asking other question. Proper course of action is simply starting a new question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Except that he asked that other question *first*, making it not a new question at all, but rather the original question that was asked to begin with...

Comment: @Servy whatever. Feel free to flag, I'm out.

Comment: duplicate of [Is it possible to mark my own question as duplicate of another?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79916/is-it-possible-to-mark-my-own-question-as-duplicate-of-another) Related: [Allow question askers to close their own questions unilaterally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10363/allow-question-askers-to-close-their-own-questions-unilaterally)